# Create a SpreadSheet Application for Android bit similar to Google Sheets

Tags: android, xml, excel, xamarin

I want to create a phone based spreadsheet application ( Xamarin , Android Native) for my collage project . After doing a bit research I found out that the functionalities used by **Google Sheets** , Office is something I am not familiar with . Google Sheets app for android has **26000 cells** in one sheet, and we can see **1500 cells** at a time (simply zooming out) with no performance issues . Those cells are clickable , selectable , editable just like text fields and button .

I know if I put **1000 Text Fields** of native xml in my app this is going to be a big problem for me.

I simply want to know the type of approach they followed , consider that the rows and columns would be adjustable in my app